# SQL Server deadlock clarity?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, deadlock

After reading [**this**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverstorageengine/archive/2006/06/05/617960.aspx) interesting article I have some questions.

This table shows a deadlock situation :

[image]

> T1 holds X lock on all rows with c1=5 on table t_lock1 while T2 holds
>   X lock on all rows with C1=1 on table t_lock2.
>
> Now each of these transactions wants to update the rows previously
>   locked by the other. This results in a deadlock.

Question #1

- Do transactions obtain locks? I know that *reading* from table is done by a *shared* lock, and *write* to a table is done using an *exclusive* lock (I'm talking about the *default* locking settings).

So it seems from this example that transaction *also* holds a lock ....is it correct?

Question #2

> ...T1 holds X lock on all rows with c1=5 on table t_lock1...

- IMHO as I've said the locking is not per row (although it can be made, but the author didn't mentioned it) - so why does he say : *on all rows with C1=5* ?

Comment: Sorry for the off topic, how did you do the pretty screenshot with the edged border?

Comment: @njk There might be others, but [snagit](http://www.techsmith.com/snagit.html) (commercial/trial) is an option.

Comment: @njk http://www.faststone.org/FSCaptureDetail.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Do transactions obtain locks?*

No. The statement that you execute - a `SELECT` or an `UPDATE` will acquire the locks. Depending on your transaction isolation level setting, the duration of how long the (shared) locks (for a reading `SELECT`) will be held differs - that's all. Shared locks normally are held only very briefly, while update and exclusive locks are held until the transaction ends. The transaction might *hold* the locks - but it's *not* the transaction that acquires the locks...

> *...T1 holds X lock on all rows with c1=5 on table t_lock1...*
>   *IMHO as I've said the locking is not per row ( although it can be made , but the author didn't mentioned it) so why does he say : on all rows with C1=5 ?*

The locking **is** per row - by default. But why do you think there's only a single row with `C1=5`? There could be multiple - possibly thousands - and the `UPDATE` statement will lock **all those rows affected** by the `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: regarding the duration : if I start a transaction and do select and doesn't commit , will the lock will remain forever ? Also the same for update ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: any transaction will either be committed, or then rolled back - at some time. If you forget to commit or rollback your transaction, then SQL Server will roll it back next time it shuts down. So it could take quite a long time before SQL Server auto-rollbacks a transaction - but nothing stays locked forever :-)

Comment: So i guess I dont understand the shared lock thing. If John reads from table , and simulatniously Paul reads the table ( both run select *) - which part is locked ( the shared one) the table ? or only the rows which each one reads ? ( or even pages ? ) ? where is the lock ? Does john locks the rows he reads or the pages he reads ? I just can't see where is the lock if it is shared...

Comment: @RoyiNamir: under the "normal" READ COMMITTED isolation level, both read operations will lock the row(s) they are reading very briefly, while reading. This just prevents a simultaneous update or delete while someone is reading. Two shared locks are compatible - so even if the read operations happen at the same time, they will both succeed. The lock is **on the row** (or the multiple rows) that a process is reading. By default the locks are always on the **row level** (one or multiple rows are locked)

Answer (score 1):

For question 1: SQL Server reads the source tables rows using U-locks, then updates them converting them to X-locks only on those rows which qualify for the update. Notice the distinction between reading many rows, then filtering them down to those which get written. Those two sets are locked differently.

As there are no selects in your queries only U and X locks are taken. S-lock are not taken for update-queries on the table being updated. This is a heuristic deadlock-avoidance scheme.

Question 2: Locking can be done at different granularity but for low row counts it is usually per row (and this can be forced). Maybe the author assumes an index on C1 which would mean that only the rows with C1=1 need to be read and locked. All other rows wouldn't be touched.

If there was no index SQL Server would indeed read all rows of the table, U-lock them while doing that and then X-lock those which satisfy C1=1. The author indeed mentiones that only rows with C1=1 are x-locked.